# Search inside Iframe for a specific tag and create another iframe

Tags: javascript, html, forms, iframe

I have the following code:

```
<FORM target="frame" onsubmit="document.getElementById('frame').style.display = 'block';" method="post" action="http://www.example.com/index.html">
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" value="" name="search-field" id="header-search-field">
<button type="submit">Search</button></FORM>

<iframe width="700" height="700" id="frame" name="frame" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

The Iframe show up correctly just submitting the form. Now I have to create a second iframe, which search for a specific tag inside the content loaded before, and show only if found.
I have to search for a specific tag:

```
<table id="item_specification" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> with all the content inside </table>
```

and show only the content inside the table ID (with table too)

Answer (score 0):

if you are not breaking cross origin policy you can access iframe document this way:

`document.getElementById('header-search-field').contentDocument`

Comment: Can you explain please ? Iframe and form, are in different domains.